# LINQ (to Entities) Query with Sorting and Grouping

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I seem to need a LINQ (to Entities against MS SQL Server) query that is a bit over my head.

My schema looks like this:

[image: Database Schema Diagram]

My task is to display all `ProductPricing` rows for a specific `ProductItem`, sorted by `ProductPricing.EffectiveDate`, and grouped by `ProductPricing.CompaniesId`.

Furthermore, I need to order the groups by `ProductItemCompanies.SortOrder`.

Note that `ProductPricing.CompaniesId` can be `null`, and that all `ProductPricing` rows where `CompaniesId` is `null` need to be grouped as a single group that is placed before all other groups.

I have made numerous attempts but I'm not clear enough of LINQ joins or grouping to get it right. My current code looks like this, but it's neither correct or even compiles.

(Note that `DefaultProductItem` is the `ProductItems` I'm displaying `ProductPricing`s for.)

```
var vendors = from pp in this.DefaultProductItem.ProductPricings
              orderby pp.EffectiveDate
              join pic in this.DefaultProductItem.ProductItemCompanies on pic.CompanyId equals pp.CompanyId &&
                  pic.ProductItemId equals this.DefaultProductItem.Id
              group pp by pp into v
              select v;
```

---

**UPDATE:**

With Tim.Tang's help, I have the following query that runs:

```
var vendors = from pp in DefaultProductItem.ProductPricings
              join pic in DefaultProductItem.ProductItemCompanies
              on pp.CompanyId equals pic.CompanyId into left
              from pic in left.DefaultIfEmpty()
              orderby pp.EffectiveDate descending, pic == null ? -1 : pic.SortOrder
              group pp by pp.CompanyId into v
              select v;
```

This is getting close, however it does not sort the resulting groups by `ProductItemCompanies.SortOrder`. Although the above query does sort by this value, that doesn't appear to affect the groups.

I know I could easily sort the groups *after the fact*, but I'm looking to make that part of the original query for efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my suggestion,hope it can help:

```
var vendors = from pp in this.DefaultProductItem.ProductPricings
              join pic in this.DefaultProductItem.ProductItemCompanies.Where(x=>x.ProductItemId == this.DefaultProductItem.Id)
              on pp.CompanyId equals pic.CompanyIdinto left
              from pic in left.DefalutIfEmpty()
              orderby pp.EffectiveDate, pic==null?0:pic.SortOrder  //sort order is INT?
              group pp by pp.CompaniesId into v
              select v;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't compile. (`pic` and `pp` on the third line give the error "The name 'pic' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'.  Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'.) Also, the `Where()` condition of `ProductItemCompanies` is redundant as all rows in `DefaultProductItem.ProductItemCompanies` will return true.

Comment: @JonathanWood exchange the order for `pp.CompanyId` and `pic.CompanyIdinto`, see my updates. don't understand the second error, this is just my suggestion

Comment: I'll try that. The second item is not an error, it's just not necessary.

Comment: There are a number of errors I'm seeing. As mentioned, the part `Where(x => x.ProductItemId == this.DefaultProductItem.Id)` is redundant because the condition will be true for all items. And also, this query doesn't sort the groups by `SortOrder`, as described.

Comment: I've added an update to my question based on working with your code.